# How can I write an algorithm to solve this formula for closest point to a set of lines in 3d

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

I am trying to understand how I can write an algorithm to solve the formula written at the end of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/61721/64943)

I know simple equations systems may be solved through matrices when you have `Ax=b` you can solve with `x = A^(-1)b` but this is a little more complicated for me

I think I should come to a form such as `A vec(c) = b` but I don't have idea how to deal with sums and dot products..

Comment: Why not write code to find the closest point to one line, and then loop over all lines, retaining the minimum?

Comment: Sorry but there isn't just one point close to one line...all the points on the line are the closest to the line..

Answer (score 0):

Use the last formula in the linked answer.To simplify it, normalize direction vectors **d(i)** (to exclude denominator)

Sum[i=1..N] (**c** - **a(i)** - **d(i)** * DotProduct(**c**-**a(i)**, **d(i)**)) = 0
   Sum[i=1..N] (**c** - **a(i)** - 
         **d(i)** * ((c.x-a(i).x) * d(i).x + (c.y-a(i).y) * d(i).y +(c.z-a(i).z) * d(i).z)) = 0
    etc

You have a system of three linear equations. You can solve this system with simple [elimination method](http://martin-thoma.com/solving-linear-equations-with-gaussian-elimination/) (which is close to the school approach for solving eq. systems)

Comment: Ok, but how can I build such a system?

Comment: Could you elaborate, MBo?